# Is it possible to apply a predicate to a proposition?

Tags: logic

I have a logical question for you which I am not really sure how to phrase, but here it goes: Is it possible to apply a predicate to a proposition? And do any of you know of some sub-logic which allows this or a paper which deals with this topic?

Example: In predicate logic, the proposition "the cat is on the mat" may be formalized as follows:

("C": is a cat; "M": is on the mat)

∃x(Cx ∧ Mx)

Or in propositional logic it may be just called "p":

"p": "the cat is on the mat"

Is it then possible to apply a predicate (e.g. "S": is a sentence) to this proposition in its entirety? I'm not sure how to formalize it, but maybe something like "Sp" or "S(∃x(Cx ∧ Mx))" which is supposed to say "'The cat is on the mat' is a sentence".

Comment: I second order and higher language your examples are perfectly reasonable.

Comment: As a picky detail, this actually says "*a* cat is on the mat" or "there is at least one cat on the mat". Also, any time you use "there exists", you formally need a bounding set, eg "there exists x in the set of all living creatures S such that..."

Answer (score 3):

In [FOL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic) (i.e. *predicate logic*) no.

We have *variables*, *constants*, *function* and *predicate* symbols.

With the first three we build *terms*.

With terms and predicate we build *atoms* (or *atomic* formulas).

Example: **x=0** and **E(x,y)** are atoms.

With *connectives* and *quantifiers* we build "complex" formulas from atomic ones, like your example: **∃x(Cx ∧ Mx)**.

Some versions allow also the use of **0**-ary predicate symbols **Pi**, that are simply the propositional letters of propositional calculus.

See Dirk van Dalen, [Logic and Structure](https://books.google.it/books?id=u0wlXPHATDcC&pg=PA56), page 56-on.

---

Your approach is more akin to "formalizing" the meta-language.

We may define (in the meta-tehory) the *class* **Sent** of *sentences* and then we can write e.g.

> **"∃x(Cx ∧ Mx)" ∈ Sent**.

---

A more "subtle" approach is via [arithmetization](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/goedel-incompleteness/#AriForLan).

For a gentle approach to *coding*, see **Ch.4**: M.Fitting, *Russell’s Paradox, Gödel’s Theorem*, of Melvin Fitting & Brian Rayman (editors), [Raymond Smullyan on Self Reference](https://books.google.it/books?id=cbRGDwAAQBAJ&pg=PR47), Springer (2017).